# Reg ex for splitting camel case words by hyphen in njs (javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, perl, nginx

I managed to create a regEx to split camel case words in Perl. However, since javascript does not support positive lookbehind I am finding it a bit difficult to create a regex that would do the same.

**Inputs and expected outputs** are **listed below** in the format **Input -> Expected Output**

1. InstallAndSetup -> install-and-setup
2. DeployingABCDefGhijk -> deploying-abc-def-ghijk (assuming abc is a noun that is frequently used)
3. OpenIDConnect        -> openid-connect
4. OAuth2Scopes->oauth2-scopes
5. APISecurity -> api-security

The perl script I used is as follows

```
 my $r = shift;
 my $uri = $r->uri;
 @uri = split /(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])(?!ID)(?!^Open$)|(?<=ABC)|(?<=API)(?=[A-Z])|(?=Connect)/,$uri;
 $uri = join ("-", @uri);
 $uri = lc($uri);
 return  $uri;
```

I am struggling with converting this same regex ((?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])(?!ID)(?!^Open$)|(?<=ABC)|(?<=API)(?=[A-Z])|(?=Connect)) to work in Javascript.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, a lot of JS environments already [support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=js-regexp-lookbehind) lookbehinds.

Comment: Still, it's not officially part of JS (just a draft), and 27-46% of web users (depending on who you ask) use a browser that doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if regular expression is the best option here as you have a mixture of fixed words and arbitrary rule but I think with a bit of lookahead:

```
(OAuth2|OpenID|[A-Z]+$|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])|[A-Z][^A-Z]+)
```

that takes OAuth2 and OpenID as special cases - otherwise any sequence of 2 or more capital letters and one capital letter followed by non-capital letters.
Difference is that this catches the parts that you want in a group (group 1) and you can walk through the matches.

If you just want to transform the text you could use this:

```
uri.replace(/(OAuth2|OpenID|[A-Z]+$|[A-Z]+(?=[A-Z][^A-Z])|[A-Z][^A-Z]+)/, function(v) { return "-"+v.toLowerCase(); });
uri = uri.substring(1);
```